# Realizar login PHP7

Tags: php, mysqli, validación, login, session

Tengo una bd mysql en la que tengo un usuario con una clave cifrada. El formulario de registro es este:
https://github.com/RafaelAybar/Mantis-rebirth/blob/master/registro.php

Tengo un lío de conceptos bastante grande. Mi script es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    $usuario = stripslashes(trim($_POST['nombre']));;
    $pass = stripslashes(trim($_POST['pass']));;

    if (isset($usuario) && isset($pass)) {
        if (strlen($pass)>= 8) {
                $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or
                        die("conexión errónea");
            mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "mantis")
                        or die ("no se puede seleccionar la BD" );
            //obtenemos el usuario y su contraseña del usuario registrado
            $consulta = "SELECT nombre, contrasena FROM jugadores WHERE EXISTS (nombre='$usuario');";
            $comprobacion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die("Autentificación fallida");
            $columnas = $comprobacion->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          if (password_verify($pass, $columnas['contrasena'])) {
              echo "Enhorabuena, te has logueado correctamente <br>";
          }


            mysqli_close($conexion);
                    }
    }
    else {
        die("Mira, te comento, debes introducir los datos, ¿VALE?");
    }
?>
```

No me autentica el usuario, siempre falla, y no entiendo por qué

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta es...?

Comment: Ya está actualizado

Comment: Sigo si ver el fallo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que el fallo estaba en la consulta, que no me acuerdo por qué me la generó php myadmin y copié y pegué sin fijarme. El código correcto es este:

```
<?php

    $usuario = stripslashes(trim($_POST['nombre']));;
    $pass = stripslashes(trim($_POST['pass']));;

    if (isset($usuario) && isset($pass)) {
        if (strlen($pass)>= 8) {
                $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or
                        die("conexión errónea");
            mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "mantis")
                        or die ("no se puede seleccionar la BD" );
            //obtenemos el usuario y su contraseña del usuario registrado
            $consulta = "SELECT contrasena FROM jugadores WHERE (nombre='$usuario');";
            $comprobacion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die("Autentificación fallida");
            $columnas = $comprobacion->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          if (password_verify($pass, $columnas['contrasena'])) {
              echo "Enhorabuena, te has logueado correctamente <br>";
          }


            mysqli_close($conexion);
                    }
    }
    else {
        die("Mira, te comento, debes introducir los datos, ¿VALE?");
    }
?>
```